# "Сидеть в интернете" или "ходить в интернет"?

Tags: интернет

Здравствуйте, столкнулась с такой проблемой: моя мама и большинство людей старшего поколения не "сидят" в Интернете, а "ходят" в Интернет. На мой взгляд, правилен первый вариант, но подтверждения этому я так и не нашла. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с каким всё-таки глаголом употреблять слово "Интернет" в данном случае.

Comment: А у меня мама именно что сидит в Интернете)))) Приходится выгонять ее спать.)))

Comment: Правилен с точки зрения какого правила? Есть ли такое правило? И самое главное **нужно ли оно**? Ну ходят и ходят и пусть дальше ходят. (Возникло видимо по аналогии с "зайти в интернет").

Answer (score 4):

Я могу в Интернете сидеть (Ого, три часа в интернете просидела!), могу бродить (т.е. без особой цели переходить со странички на страничку: посмотрела новости дня, на "Одноклассниках" проверила сообщения и новости от друзей, новые вопросы и ответы на форуме "Русский язык" и т.д.), могу облазить весь Интернет (гипербола, конечно) в поисках срочно нужной информации. А сыну говорю так - все, с домашними делами закончила, пошла в компьютер (это может быть и Интернет, и просто работа с документами, но "пошла в Интернет" не говорю). Т.е. каждый глагол имеет свой оттенок значения, тут я с Сержем согласна. А как правильно? Время покажет, словари подскажут - попозже...

Answer (score 3):

Моя
 мама иногда употребляет даже "сидеть в компьютере", но по мне такое 
употребление не правильно. *Сидеть в интернете* я в слышу уже лет 15, с 
момента моего знакомства с компьютерером и Сетью, так что такое 
выражение мне не претит. В интернете можно **сидеть**, по нему можно 
**ползать**, там можно **зависать** и в него можно **заходить** (без приставки, *ходить в 
интернет(е)*, никогда не слышал).

Comment: Употребляется не "ходить в Интернете", а ходить "в Интернет".

Answer (score 2):

С появлением Интернета,  а потом и соц.сетей, слово "сидеть" приобрело дополнительное значение: проводить время в Интернете. Видимо под влиянием этого значения: ***СИДЕТЬ 3.
Находиться в каком-л. месте в каких-л. целях (обычно длительное время). С. в гостях. С. в засаде. С. с друзьями в кафе, в ресторане
(проводить так своё время).***
Сидеть в Интернете означает долгое время быть в Интернете, что нельзя сказать о "пользоваться", где нет никакого дополнительного оттенка.

Answer (score 2):

В Интернет заходят. Там можно сидеть, бродить, лазить, зависать, ну, а для кого-то прывычнее слово - ходить. В Интернете можно всё!

Answer (score 1):

Глаголом "ходить"  мы обозначаем регулярно повторяющееся  действие: ходить на работу, в школу, в магазин, на тренировку.

В Интернет  мы заходим и выходим, например:

Проблема: не могу зайти в интернет через wi-fi.  Девять причин немедленно выйти из Интернета.

Но ходить в Интернет тоже можно, если мы говорим  о  постоянном пользовании Интернетом, например:

В Интернет ходить мама не велит. 
Россияне будут чаще ходить в Интернет. 
Зачем ты ходишь в интернет? 
Сегодня люди «ходят» в Интернет, чтобы найти решения своих проблем и научиться применять актуальные знания. 
Кто-нибудь ходит в Интернет с мобильника? 
Действительно ли в Интернет придется ходить по паспорту?

Возможно, выражение "ходить в Интернет" носит разговорный характер, а в книжной речи следует использовать кавычки.

Comment: Я бы сказал, ходить в интернет  - подразумевая Интернет-клуб. Тогда все в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Я не взял бы ни одного из предложенных Вами вариантов, а написал бы: "используют Интернет" или "пользуются Интернетом".

Comment: И вы бы сказали сыну "пошел пользоваться Интернетом"?